# How to replace byte

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I made a application which allows a specific user to choose a PDF file from his device and put pagenumbers on it.
After that the file will show in a specific directory as "PDF.pdf"

But my problem is that files will a large memory, makes the application crash.

*The Error message:* [image: Error Alert]

**Code:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;

namespace NummerierePDF
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private string theFile = "";
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(theFile) || !File.Exists(theFile))
                return;
            byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(theFile);
            iTextSharp.text.Font blackFont = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 12, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK);
            using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(bytes);
                using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, stream))
                {
                    int pages = reader.NumberOfPages;
                    for (int i = 1; i <= pages; i++)
                    {
                        ColumnText.ShowTextAligned(stamper.GetOverContent(i), Element.ALIGN_RIGHT, new Phrase(i.ToString(), blackFont), 568f, 15f, 0);
                    }
                }
                bytes = stream.ToArray();
            }
            File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\Users\user\Pictures\Camera Roll\PDF.pdf", bytes);
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var FD = new System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog();
            if (FD.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
                theFile = FD.FileName;
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to change byte to a other method like int.
But as you guessed it, it wont work.

Comment: can you not just write to a `FileStream` in the first place, and leave the `MemoryStream` out of it? i.e. `using(var stream = File.Create(path)) { ... }` ? Ditto with the reader - no need to `ReadAllBytes` here - it looks like `PdfReader` takes a `Stream`, so give it `File.OpenRead(theFile)`

Comment: My knowledge and english is not good enough to understand your answer. Can you explain it a little bit longer if you can ? That would be so nice of you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on an earlier comment - basically, stop trying to hold entire files in memory as contiguous arrays - the API is `Stream`-based, and you have `FileStream` available to you, so:

```
iTextSharp.text.Font blackFont = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 12,
    iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK);
using (Stream source = File.OpenRead(theFile))
using (Stream dest = File.Create(@"C:\Users\user\Pictures\Camera Roll\PDF.pdf"))
{
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(source);
    using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, dest))
    {
        int pages = reader.NumberOfPages;
        for (int i = 1; i <= pages; i++)
        {
            ColumnText.ShowTextAligned(stamper.GetOverContent(i), Element.ALIGN_RIGHT,
                new Phrase(i.ToString(), blackFont), 568f, 15f, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

I can't test that from here, but it *looks* like it should work.

Based on a quick search, it *might* also work as:

```
iTextSharp.text.Font blackFont = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 12,
    iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK);
using (Stream dest = File.Create(@"C:\Users\user\Pictures\Camera Roll\PDF.pdf"))
{
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(theFile);
    // ...
```

Comment: I will read your answer and look your thoughts up in the internet. I still try to figure out what you did but thank you. You are the MVP!

Comment: @Burak I don't know which concepts you're familiar with, but an *array* (`byte[]`) is a single contiguous chunk of memory, and it gets tricky when the size gets big; `Stream`, however, is an API that allows *incremental* IO access to some resource (in this case a file), meaning: you don't need to hold all the memory at once - you can just read the next 10, 100, 1000 bytes (whatever), process it, and repeat. As such: `Stream` (or more recently "pipeline") APIs are far preferable for large resources. I replaced the array usage with `Stream`, nothing more